# Receive incoming public IP addresses through VPN?

Tags: vpn, ip, iptables, openvpn, tunnel

For a short spell, I ran a VPN server with OpenVPN + iptables on a VPS I purchased, and would tunnel my home server through it, in order to mask my home server's IP address from visitors. This worked fantastically, until I realized that all incoming connections received from my primary server through the VPN were being registered as my VPN's client IP, completely ruining any kind of possibility of banning specific connections.

Is it possible to make my primary server receive public requesting IPs through my VPN? From my perspective, it sounds like I'd have to use a really "hacky" method for doing this, but if there's a built-in way of doing this through OpenVPN, I'd gladly re-open my VPS and use it.

Thank you.

EDIT: Have searched around a long while for an answer, but have not found a solution (Or one clear enough for me to comprehend). I've also experimented with services such as CloudFlare, however, they're mainly oriented for websites, and not services that don't use html. A VPN tunnel still seems like the best solution, if only my hosting machine were able to see an incoming connection's real IP address, and not a local mask.

Comment: I'd think your better bet is to block them at the OpenVPN level at the VPS instead of at your home server since, as you mentioned, all your home server sees is traffic from the VPS.

Comment: That sounds like a "hacky" method, unfortunately, but certainly possible to an extent... However, I have specific services running that require direct public IP visibility in order to function properly. Example; only disabling some things for a connecting client, and not banning them entirely.

Comment: don't know but sounds like you may be talking about something along the lines of VPN without NAT. I have heard that you can definitely have a VPN without NAT

Comment: That looks like the right term for what I'm trying to do I think, but searching around doesn't really lead to anything I can easily set up with Openbox. If I'm to have to stick without, and migrate my server setup entirely to a VPS, I can eventually do this, but it would be fantastic to keep on being able to manage my server hardware setup from home without having to pay storage costs, etc.

Comment: If there's any other method I could go about perusing that allows me to keep using my home server network, but at the same time host publicly with another IP address other than my home network, I'd gladly look into it... A VPN was just the first idea I had for this kind of thing.